# Request of Ajax with Laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I am trying to make an example of Ajax request with Laravel 5.4.

The test example is simple, just enter a numeric value in an input = text field in my View and leave the field to send to the Controller, then add + 10 to that value and then return that value to my View so that it can displayed on an alert.

**HTML** : viewteste.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">      
            Valor: <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**: The js file is inside viewteste.blade.php, I just split it to make it easier to interpret.

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#valor").on('blur', function()
       {
            valor = $(this).val();    
            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:"{{ URL::to('/teste/valor') }}",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    "valor": valor
                },
                success:function(data){
                    alert('Success');
                },
                error:function(){
                  alert('Error');
                },
            });


       });
    });
</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/teste',      'TesteAjaxController@index');
Route::post('/teste/valor', 'TesteAjaxController@valor');
```

**Controller**

```
class TesteAjaxController extends Controller
{
     public function index()
    {
        return view('painel.viewteste');
    }

    public function valor(Request $request)
    {
        $valor= $request->input('valor');
        $valor += 10;
        return $valor; // How do I return in json? in case of an error message?

    }
}
```

Always when I try to send the request via ajax it goes to alert ('Error'). is it that I'm doing something wrong in sending the ajax or route?

Comment: error:function(e){
                  console.log(e);
                }, Here you can find what kind of error you are facing

Comment: There is no `valor` method in your controller, which you are accessing via `'TesteAjaxController@valor'`

Comment: Please add valor() function in your controller.

Comment: There is no `meta` tag in your example. Try to add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to `head`.

Comment: Check the Laravel error log there detail description of error would be present check what it says, chances are there is an error in server side script. your client side scripts looks okay.

Comment: I checked the code and refaced the changes you suggested, and it was a total mistake of my attention, now it worked! Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to return a json response. you need to use.

```
response()->json([
 'somemessage' => 'message',
 'valor' => $valor
]);
```

UPDATE: you are getting an error alert because i think your route method doesnt match your controller methods.

```
Route::post('/teste/valor', 'TesteAjaxController@valor');
```

where in your controller you have

```
public function cep() ...
```